# Simple Unity game gets slow after admob integration

Tags: c#, android, performance, unity-game-engine, admob

I made a simple 2d game with not many objects and it runs fine on my Xperia ST. But when i integrated admobs to show both banner and interstitial ads on game over screen the gameplay lags and gets slow.

My code for admob and how they are used is given below

Player Script

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerMotion : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject gameOverTag,spawner,camera,adObject;
SpawnScript spawnScript;
GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript adScript;
// Use this for initialization
void Awake() {
    adObject=GameObject.Find("Ads");// ads is a game object which was kept from main menu screen
    }

void Start () {
    spawnScript= spawner.GetComponent<SpawnScript> ();
    //adScript=camera.GetComponent<GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript> ();//GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript is         the ad script
    adScript=adObject.GetComponent<GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript> ();
    adScript.hideBanner ();
    adScript.requestInterstitial ();
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
//some more code
            }
    }
public void Movement()
{
    //some code
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other){
    //some code
}
void OnGUI(){
            if (gameOver) {
                    if((adScript.timesInterstitalRequested)%5==0)
                    adScript.ShowInterstitial ();
                    else
                    adScript.showBanner ();

                    //some more code
            }
    }
}
```

Here is GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript Code

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

// Example script showing how to invoke the Google Mobile Ads Unity plugin.
public class GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript : MonoBehaviour
{

private BannerView bannerView;
private InterstitialAd interstitial;
public int timesBannerRequested=0,timesInterstitalRequested=0;

void Awake() {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (this);
}
void Start()
{

}

public void requestBanner(){
    //Requesting BannerView
    timesBannerRequested = timesBannerRequested + 1;
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-asdas";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-asd";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif
    bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.SmartBanner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest requestBanner = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    bannerView.LoadAd(requestBanner);
    //bannerView.Hide ();
}

public void requestInterstitial(){
    timesInterstitalRequested = timesInterstitalRequested + 1;
    //Requesting Interstitial
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitIdInterstitial = "ca-app-pub-dfada";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitIdInterstitial = "ca-app-pub-asdas";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitIdInterstitial = "INSERT_IOS_INTERSTITIAL_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #else
    string adUnitIdInterstitial = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitIdInterstitial);
    AdRequest requestInterstitial = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    interstitial.LoadAd(requestInterstitial);
}

public void showBanner()
{
    bannerView.Show ();
}
public void destroyBanner()
{
    bannerView.Destroy ();
    }

public void hideBanner()
{
    bannerView.Hide ();
    }
public void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        print("Interstitial is not ready yet.");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: From experience I find that well formatted code gets the best of help here on SO.

Comment: @FunctionR I did not understand what exactly you meant

Answer (score 0):

Your logic seems solid from a first glance,

I would however optimize the OnGUI function. since this is the most vital function of all,
when considering the mobile hardware.

```
void OnGUI(){
        if (gameOver) {
                if(adScript.bannerShowing == false) {
                  if((adScript.timesInterstitalRequested)%5==0)
                    adScript.ShowInterstitial ();
                   else
                    adScript.showBanner ();
                }
        }
}
```

Then add a bannerShowing boolean on the GoogleMobileAdsDemoScript code and make it true when visible
and false when the banner is hidden,
its a bad idea to call ShowInterstital or showBanner multiple times in OnGUI since it all runs on a single thread.

Comment: But here as you can see its only being called when gameover is true.. But when game is over the game is not slow the game is slow when the scene is loaded and run for the first time only

Answer (score 0):

Google Admob uses some very big 8MB DLL if you integrate that into Unity project.
Common feedback is: the App starts slower and the app loads scenes with Admob slow for the fist time.

You may try to implement native Android plugin into your Unity app. Basically that plugin would be written in Java and it would work fast.